# Couldn't find Aco node identified by "Array ( [Aco0.model] => model [Aco0.foreign_key] => U ) "

Tags: cakephp

I'm going through the following links to use Acl component in my application

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists--net-1345

in usersController i have a function to install aros and acos

```
public function install(){

    $aro = $this->Acl->Aro;
    $aco = $this->Acl->Aco;


    $aro_groups = array(

        0 => array(

            'alias' => 'admin'
        ),

        1 => array(

            'alias' => 'operator'
        ),

        2 => array(

            'alias' => 'user'
        ),

    );

    $aco_groups = array(

        0 => array(

            'alias' => 'User'
        ),

        1 => array(

            'alias' => 'Supplier'
        ),

        2 => array(

            'alias' => 'Inventory'
        ),

        3 => array(

            'alias' => 'Invoice'
        ),

        4 => array(

            'alias' => 'Incentive'
        ),

        5 => array(

            'alias' => 'Promotion'
        ),

        6 => array(

            'alias' => 'Feedback'
        ),

        7 => array(

            'alias' => 'Message'
        ),

        8 => array(

            'alias' => 'History'
        ),

    );


    foreach($aro_groups as $data):

        $aro->create();
        $aro->save($data);


    endforeach;


    foreach($aco_groups as $data):

        $aco->create();
        $aco->save($data);


    endforeach;

    foreach($aco_groups as $data):

        $this->Acl->allow('admin',$data);
        $this->Acl->allow('operator',$data);

    endforeach;




}
```

my user model is as follows:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Role' => array(
        'className' => 'Role',
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    if(isset($this->data['User']['password']))
    {
        $this->data['User']['password']= AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);


    }
}



public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));



public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
        $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
    }
    if (!$groupId) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
    }
}

public function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model' => 'Role', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['role_id']);
}
```

role model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);



public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));



public function parentNode() {

        return null;

}
```

now, when I try to access `/users/install` just to check that all relations are successfully created or not, i'm getting this error

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aco node identified by "Array ( [Aco0.model] => model [Aco0.foreign_key] => U ) "

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'id' [CORE\Cake\Model\AclNode.php, line 140]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parentNode function in your User model, you have group_id instead of role_id.
Replace all occurrences of group_id to role_id in your User model and you should be ok and also Replace Group with Role

```
public function parentNode() {
if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
    return null;
}
if (isset($this->data['User']['role_id'])) {
    $roleId = $this->data['User']['role_id'];
} else {
    $roleId = $this->field('role_id');
}
if (!$roleId) {
    return null;
} else {
    return array('Role' => array('id' => $roleId));
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry I post here the older parentNode() when i was using groups table, my new method is same as yours